# DRF Testing, Login view does work when loging in from Postman, but it throws error in APITestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF and for learning I am writing test for my DRF Rest API. I am trying to test Login view, however, the test is failing even though I am providing correct credentials. Unusual thing is that it works perfectly fine when I am making a login request from Postman

I tried analyzing the data I provide, however I don't find any issues. In the test case I create new User and then try to log in.

My Test case:

```
    def test_login_user(self):
        """
        Ensure user can log in
        """
        username = 'TestUserLogin'
        password = 'test978453442'

        url = reverse('login-list')

        user = User.objects.create(
          email='testUserLogin@test.com', 
          first_name='Matheus',
          last_name='Smith',
          password=password,
          title='professor',
          username=username,
          groups=Group.objects.get(name=GROUPS[0])
        )

        response = self.client.post(url, {'username': username, 'password': password}, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My Token Generator class

```
class CustomExpiringObtainAuthToken(ObtainAuthToken):
      def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Override!

        Create token everytime this endpoint is called
        """
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']

        if hasattr(user, 'auth_token'):
          user.auth_token.delete()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key})
```

My Login View:

```
class LoginView(ViewSet):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        return CustomExpiringObtainAuthToken().as_view()(request=request._request)
```

Comment: Try to use `user.set_password(password); user.save()` in your test

Comment: It works!. So I guess when I am using a model to create an ob ject, the password is not hashed and while using `set_password` the password is hashed correctly

Comment: Yeah that's right.